# Any rsync frontend that supports SSH for Linux?

Tags: ssh, rsync, frontend

any rsync frontend that works with SSH for Linux ?

I tried Unison, but i think it needs the server has installed also Unison.

Regards

Javi

Comment: Just to be clear, is Linux the OS of the client, the server, or both?

Answer (score 1):

All Linux rsync clients should support the -e option.

```
rsync -essh foo bar
```